# Can't get click or keyup event to fire

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

So I've managed to get `*ngFor` working to output my data, however when I try to fire an event when something changes nothing seems to happen.

Here's my HTML:

```
    <ion-content padding class="home">
      {{ searchString }}
      {{ selectedOption }}
      <ion-searchbar (keyup)="onKey(box.value)"></ion-searchbar>


      <ion-list radio-group>
        <ion-list-header>
          <span class="listHeader">Items</span><span class="pullRight">Showing 3 of 3</span>
        </ion-list-header>

        <ion-item *ngFor="let x of Options" (click)="changeSelection(x)">
          <ion-label>{{ x.displayName }}</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="{{ x.id }}"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

I would expect the `(click)` event to fire and run the `changeSelection` method in the javascript:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    reportOptions;
    selectedOption;
    searchString;
    constructor(private navController: NavController) {

    this.Options = [    {
                                displayName: 'Test Option 1',
                                id: '1'
                            },
                            {
                                displayName: 'Test Option 2',
                                id: '2'
                            },
                            {
                                displayName: 'Test Option 3',
                                id: '3'
                            }
                          ];
    this.selectedOption = 'Hello';

    }

    changeSelection(x) {
        this.selectedOption = 'world';
    }
    onKey(value: string) {
        this.searchString= value;
    }

}
```

Can't see what I'm missing here, is there an import I'm missing or something more complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're missing to bind those elements to the proper properties by using `[(ngModel)]`.

So, first related to the `ion-radio` elements, you've added the *radio-group* attribute

`<ion-list radio-group>`

but you forget to bind those radio buttons to the `selectedOption` property from your `Component`. By adding that `ngModel` everytime you select a radio, the value will be automatically assigned to the `selectedOption`. If you still want to grab the text of that radio, you can subscribe to the `ionSelect` event from the `ion-radio` element like this:

```
<ion-radio value="{{ x.id }}" (ionSelect)="changeSelection(x)"></ion-radio>
```

And then you'd have to add that method in your component:

```
public changeSelection(x: any) {
    this.selectedOptionText = x.displayName;
}
```

About the `ion-searchbar`, the error is the same, that element is not binded to any property from your component. You can bind it to the `searchString` property by doing:

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchString"></ion-searchbar>
```

And if you still want to run some code with the *blur* event is triggered, you can subscribe to any of the [Output events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/#output-events) from the `ion-searchbar` by adding the event name between () and assigning a method from your component. for example, to bind the `ionBlur` event with our `onBlur` method, you'd do it like this:

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchString" (ionBlur)="onBlur()"></ion-searchbar>
```

You can find a [working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aks3eNxcDU35leLWWpYe?p=preview) with your code working.

Comment: Glad to be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

The `changeSelection` method would be invoked if there was one.
I don't see any in the code you posted.

Comment: How do I implement this?
I've added a method called changeSelection() but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Without seeing the code no useful help can be given. I only see a changeReport method. Typo?

Comment: yeah that was a typo, I've corrected it in the question. 

This is all the code (minus some html) for the page